# Queryset fetched in view and passed to template

Tags: django, django-templates

What happens if a queryset that was already evaluated in view, is passed to a template? Iterating through it would use the cache or it trigger another db query?

views.py

```
books = Books.objects.all()
len (books) #from db
for book in books: # from cache
    ....
```

template

```
for book in books: #uses cache or db?
    ....
```

Comment: Why would it cause another query if you've already evaluated it?

Answer (score 0):

It triggers another DB query. Try sending the data in JSON which will not make any DB queries and will be a lot quicker.

Or you can do :

```
books = Books.objects.values() // this will returns dictionaries
books = Books.objects.value_list() // this returns tuples when iterated over.
```

If you have a large set of data then don't go for template rendering with the query set. But for smaller data, it works just fine.

Hope this helps.